# How do you match two data frames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 data frames that has more than 200 rows. I would like to find a match in all values in each row in df1 and find a match in df2 and return the row numbers and values. I have tried this code below doesn't work for all the rows. If there's a way to use the same code as below, but for all the rows instead of selected row. If not its okay for a different code.

```
vals_to_find = set(df1.iloc[0])
mask = df2.loc[:, "Num1":].apply(lambda x: 
len(vals_to_find.intersection(x)) > 2, axis=1)
print(df2[mask])
```

My data frames.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[5,10,21],[22,15,7],[6,23,10],[4,34,57]],columns = ['Num1','Num2','Num3'])


df2    = pd.DataFrame([[100,1,2,4,5,6,8],
                   [87,1,6,10,22,23,34],
                   [99,1,12,13,34,45,46],
                   [64,1,10,14,29,32,33],
                   [55,1,22,13,23,33,35],
                   [66,1,6,7,8,9,10],
                   [77,1,2,3,5,6,8],
                   [811,1,2,5,6,8,10], 
                   [118,1,7,8,22,44,56],
                   [117,1,66,44,47,87,91],
                   [299,2,4,7,20,21,22],
                   [187,3,6,10,12,23,39],
                   [199,4,12,24,34,56,57],
                   [264,3,7,8,9,10,33],
                   [50,6,8,10,23,33,35],
                   [212,4,6,12,18,19,20],
                   [45,3,7,23,35,56,88],
                   [801,1,2,4,6,28,39], 
                   [258,2,3,4,9,10,41],
                   [220,5,6,10,27,57,81]],
                   columns = ['Row', 'Num1','Num2','Num3','Num4','Num5','Num6'])


    Row  Num1  Num2  Num3  Num4  Num5  Num6
1    87     1     6    10    22    23    34   Match 6,23,10
11  187     3     6    10    12    23    39   Match 6,23,10
14   50     6     8    10    23    33    35   Match 6,23,10
12  199     4    12    24    34    56    57   Match 4,34,57
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. I don't understand the output of your code. Why row 87 is an answer? It does not have a pairwise match with any of the rows of df1.

Comment: Updated my question. hopeful its more understandable

Comment: So, you are using num1,2,...,6 from df2 to compare with num1,2,3 from df1?

Comment: I have updated my answer, you can check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm no so sure if I understand your question correctly. I assume you mean you are trying to find rows from `df2` that have at least one value in common with `df1`. One of the ways to do this task is to match each row of `df2` with `df1` and find the `max` matching number for them. Finally use this number to select rows.

```
max_matching_number = df2[['Num1','Num2','Num3']].apply(lambda row: (row == df1).sum(axis=1).max(),axis=1)
df2[max_matching_number>=1]
```

The output of the code above will be :

```
    Row  Num1  Num2  Num3  Num4  Num5  Num6
1    87     1     6    10    22    23    34
3    64     1    10    14    29    32    33
5    66     1     6     7     8     9    10
10  299     2     4     7    20    21    22
11  187     3     6    10    12    23    39
12  199     4    12    24    34    56    57
14   50     6     8    10    23    33    35
15  212     4     6    12    18    19    20
19  220     5     6    10    27    57    81
```

---

### Update

What you added into your comments, shows that you want to calculate the intersection of numbers between two dataframes. It can be done in the following way :

```
def find_max_matching_number(row):
    return df1.apply(lambda r: len(row.intersection(set(r))),axis=1).max()

mask = df2[df2.columns[1:]].apply(lambda row:find_max_matching_number(set(row)),axis=1)>2

result = df2[mask]
print(result)
```

and here is the output :

```
    Row  Num1  Num2  Num3  Num4  Num5  Num6
1    87     1     6    10    22    23    34
11  187     3     6    10    12    23    39
12  199     4    12    24    34    56    57
14   50     6     8    10    23    33    35
```